# Wrong data type being passed to Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple chat app to get started with ASP.NET and my partial view seems to be receiving the data type passed to Index.cshtml instead of the data I intended to pass to PersistantMessagesPartial.cshtml.

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebChat.Areas.Identity.Data.AppUser]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebChat.Models.MessageModel]'.***

In HomeController.cs:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("debug1");
        return View(await _AppUserDBContext.userList.ToListAsync());
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> _PersistantMessagesPartial()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("debug2");
        return PartialView("_PersistantMessagesPartial", await _MessageModelDBContext.messageList.ToListAsync());
    }
```

In _PersistantMessagesPartial.cshtml:

```
@model List<WebChat.Models.MessageModel>
<script>
    console.log("test");
</script>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <script>
        console.log("MessagePartial");
        console.log(@item.Contents);
    </script>
}
```

How can I render the partial, in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<partial name="_PersistantMessagesPartial" />
```

Index.cshtml receives a list of AppUser, and that works correctly. I'm not sure how to make _PersistantMessagesPartial receive a list of MessageModel instead of the list of AppUser.

Comment: You have to add the `model` to your partial view tag. Like this: `<partial name="_PersistantMessagesPartial" model="@Model.GoesHere"  />`.  I think it is getting the model from your Index view passed to it. It doesn't call your `_PersistantMessagesPartial` in your controller, you might need to make a view model or turn the partial view and action into a [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @zgood suggestion of view component is valid, and preferred. However, the info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2 can help you pass in a model that is distinct from the parent's `ViewDataDictionary`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the list of objects I would create a class:

```
public class PersistantMessagesPartialModel{
    public List<WebChat.Models.MessageModel> Messages{get;set;}
}
```

and pass the object using [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1#for) attribute like this:

```
@model IndexViewModel

<partial name="_PersistantMessagesPartial.cshtml" for="PersistantMessagesPartialModel" />
```

Then your partial view would look like:

```
@model PersistantMessagesPartialModel

@foreach(var item in Model.Messages)
{
    <script>
        console.log("MessagePartial");
        console.log(@item.Contents);
    </script>
}
```

The controller would look like this:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
  {
       var viewModel = new IndexViewModel(){
          PersistantMessagesPartialModel = new 
          PersistantMessagesPartialModel(){
                Messages = await 
           _AppUserDBContext.userList.ToListAsync()
            };
      return View(viewModel);
   }
```

The `IndexViewModel` would look like:

```
public class IndexViewModel{
    public PersistantMessagesPartialModel  
    PersistantMessagesPartialModel {get;set;}
}
```

I know that ASP.NET MVC allows you to define a model of the given page as a list of objects however I believe in the rule that each .cshtml page should have a **single** model class. It gives you huge flexibility when you want to add some new logic to the view. Just imagine a simple case when you want to add some if statement in your partial view which would work based on some value set in the backend of your app. In such a case you would need to use ViewBag, ViewData objects to pass it to the view and this is a bit harder to maintain especially if your app is big.
In my solution, you would just add this extra field to the `PersistantMessagesPartialModel`, and even in a case when you want to do some renaming etc. its just faster and safer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Where would the partial get the instantiated PersistantMessagesPartialModel from? Same question, different wording: where would the for attribute grab the Model from if not passed using Views?

Comment: E.g. you have the Home.cshtml view. This view's `@model` would be HomeViewModel. It would look like `public class HomeViewModel { public PersistantMessagesPartialModel PersistantMessagesPartialModel {get; set;} // and some other properties}`. When you add the `<partial name="_PersistantMessagesPartial.cshtml" for="PersistantMessagesPartialModel" />` to the Home.cshtml the `for` attribute will take the value from the property of `HomeViewModel`

Comment: In different case e.g. if you want to add your partial view on a _layout.cshtml then i would use `ViewBag` in the action of the controller to set the partial model and pass the value using `model` attribute e.g. `<partial name="_PersistantMessagesPartial" model="@ViewBag['PersistantMessagesPartialModel']" />`

Comment: If you still dont understand something feel free to ask questions I'll try to explain you everything with more details if needed ;)

Comment: Oh, so you the HomeViewModel is acting like a data wrapper. I have it working nicely now, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. Well, it is more to make the partial views flexible so you can use them on other views if needed multiple times.